# Script not executing under CRON every time ie runs for a bit then stops - 16.04

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

So I have a bash script running every 5 minutes under CRON.

CRON for the user

```
*/5 * * * * /home/lusiphur/torrent_copy.sh >> /home/lusiphur/torrent.log
```

Permissions on the script

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lusiphur lusiphur         833 Aug  3 18:14 torrent_copy.sh
```

The log file it is outputting to shows the following (this is the relevant snippet)

```
Start + 2017-08-0423:20  
Finish + 2017-08-0423:20  
Start + 2017-08-0508:35
```

This is output from the script showing it's start and finish time.

However, cron.log thinks it has kept running the script

```
Aug  4 23:20:01 Hyena CRON[16905]: (lusiphur) CMD (/home/lusiphur/torrent_copy.sh >> /home/lusiphur/torrent.log)
Aug  4 23:20:04 Hyena CRON[16903]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  4 23:25:01 Hyena CRON[16929]: (lusiphur) CMD (/home/lusiphur/torrent_copy.sh >> /home/lusiphur/torrent.log)
Aug  4 23:25:01 Hyena CRON[16927]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  4 23:30:01 Hyena CRON[16933]: (lusiphur) CMD (/home/lusiphur/torrent_copy.sh >> /home/lusiphur/torrent.log)
Aug  4 23:30:01 Hyena CRON[16931]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  4 23:35:01 Hyena CRON[16941]: (lusiphur) CMD (/home/lusiphur/torrent_copy.sh >> /home/lusiphur/torrent.log)
Aug  4 23:35:01 Hyena CRON[16939]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I note that after I log back on to the box, the next execution of the script is successful. Once I log off, it runs for a bit then stops.

Comment: Based on your outputs, it looks like `cron` **is** running your script at the specified intervals; if it's not giving the expected output that would be down to the script itself, not `cron`. Perhaps it becomes unable to write to `/home/lusiphur/torrent.log`?

Comment: The other actions in the script are also not performed. Which is the base issue. There are a bunch of copies to a remote server which again, only work periodically.

Comment: Again that would be a matter of debugging the script - first step would be to capture its standard error stream (which is currently being discarded) by redirecting it to the log file i.e. add `2>&1` to the end of your cron command

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the home directory the script and log file were in was on an encrypted drive. When the user logged out the drive was unmounted. Hence CRON was unable to launch the script. Moved the script etc and all was fine.